# Excel: When ID is ______, perform calculation using the date of the first occurence of _________ ID?

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to create a column that counts the number of days between each entry and the first entry for the same ID.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to be working: =IF(F4=F3,G4-INDEX($F:$G,MATCH(F4,F2:G1527,0),SMALL(G:G,1)),0)

*F:F=ID,G:G=Date

```
ID      DATE
AHLAHL  6/26/14 0:00
AHLAHL  6/26/14 0:00
AHLAHL  6/27/14 0:00
AHLAHL  6/27/14 0:00
AHLAHL  6/28/14 0:00
AHLAHL  6/28/14 0:00
ashbau  6/24/14 0:00
ASHBAU  6/24/14 0:00
ASHBAU  6/25/14 0:00
ASHBAU  6/25/14 0:00
ashbau  6/26/14 0:00
ASHBAU  6/26/14 0:00
ATZJUS  4/16/14 0:00
ATZJUS  4/16/14 0:00
ATZJUS  4/17/14 0:00
ATZJUS  4/17/14 0:00
ATZJUS  4/18/14 0:00
ATZJUS  4/18/14 0:00
Atzjus  4/20/14 0:00
ATZJUS  4/20/14 0:00
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is the formula returning vs what are you expecting to see?? Just saying "it doesn't seem to be working" is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should work:

```
=G2-VLOOKUP(F2,F:G,2,FALSE)
```

`VLOOKUP` finds the first entry that matches the leftmost column of the data array (`F:G` in this example) and then returns the value in column 2 in the same row. Then we just subtract that from the date in column 2. You'll want to enter this in row 2 of your spreadsheet and drag it down alongside the data. (If you're starting in a row other then 2, change the `F2` and `G2` above.)